# using ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager with asp:ScriptManager

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am attempting to use the ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender in my content.aspx page. The problem is that I have an asp:ScriptManager tag within my site.master page. How do I utilize the ScriptManagerProxy to replace the ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager in my content.aspx page.

*** The code below is my site.Master ***

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="cms.master.cs" Inherits="ccib.cms" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %>>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">



        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <%--<asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>

        </asp:ScriptManager>


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="container">

                   <div class="row">

                        <div class="container body-content">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                          </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                            <footer>
                                  <p> &copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> </p>
                            </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*** The code below is my content.aspx ***

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Content.aspx.cs" Inherits="ccib.mycms.Content" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  

    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender 
        ID="CalendarExtender2"
        TargetControlID="txtStartDate"   
        Format="dd/MM/yyyy" 
        runat="server">

    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find a work around for this although I am not sure it is ideal. For those also having this problem I did manage to get this to work by adding a second master page were I initiated the ToolScriptManager before the ScriptManagerProxy. The second Site.Master just uses the ScriptManagerProxy. The issue seems to be that I am unable to use a ScriptManagerProxy within my content pages to serve AJAX controls that utilize the ToolScriptManager. This will work until I find a better way. Below is my code for others to reference.

*** Site-AJAX.Master ***

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" ></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
        <%--Framework Scripts--%>
        <%--<asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site Scripts--%>
    </Scripts>

</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

**Site.Master (For content pages that do require ToolScriptManager)**

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <%--<asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>

    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

**Also do not forget to add the toolkit to the web.config file.**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <pages>
          <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
          </controls>
      </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```